# How to merge arrays of hashes based on keys of hashes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

I want to merge these two arrays based on uniqueness:

```
"template_variables": [{
    "info_top": "Some string"
}, {
    "info_bottom": "Other string"
}],


"user_variables": [{
    "info_top": "Default string"
}, {
    "info_bottom": "Other default string"
}, {
    "other_info": "Default number"
}]
```

So if I start with the `user_variables` array and add `template_variables` to it, replacing hashes where matches are found.

My desired output would be:

```
"new_variables": [{
    "info_top": "Some string"
}, {
    "info_bottom": "Other string"
}, {
    "other_info": "Default number"
}]
```

I've tried `user_variables.merge(template_variables)` and variations on that, but that's not suitable for an array of hashes, it seems.

How do I do this?

Comment: What is the desired output to your above example?

Comment: Will the values within the `template_variables` array and the `user_variables` array, always be a hash's with a single key?  Or could you get something like this: `"template_variables" : [{var1: 'some str', var2: 'str in same has as var1'}, {var3: '3rd str in a different hash'}]`

Comment: Like @RSB said, please add the desired output. Also, please provide us with what your solution (or at least, your exercises) look like.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question.

Comment: @br3nt They'll always be structured the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(first_array + second_array).uniq{|hash| hash.keys.first}
```

but your data structure sucks.

Comment: Mind explaining why? Also, your answer didn't work for me.

Comment: An array of _n_ single element hashes, all with different keys, instead of a single hash with _n_ elements. Also, what exactly does not work? What result do you get?

Comment: It's been _hugely_ simplified for this post, but yeah, I get your point, thanks. Although your code just returns both hashes without any overwriting.

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer because you helped me the most. I ended up cleaning the data structure and using a `merge` on it.

Answer (score 1):

If:

```
hash = { "template_variables":
         [{"info_top":    "Some string"},
          {"info_bottom": "Other string"}],

         "user_variables":
         [{"info_top": "Default string"},
          {"info_bottom": "Other default string"},
          {"other_info": "Default number"}]
       }
```

Then try this:

```
values = hash.values.flatten.reverse.inject(&:merge!).map { |k,v| { k => v } }
new_hash = {"new_variables": values}
```

returns:

```
{ :new_variables =>
  [{:other_info => "Default number"},
   {:info_bottom => "Other string"},
   {:info_top => "Some string"}]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do something like

```
 kk = {"aa": [{a: 1}, {b: 2}]}
 jk = {"bb": [{a:3}, {d: 4}]}
 (kk.values+jk.values).flatten.uniq{|hash| hash.keys.first}
```

Which is similar to Mladen Jablanović post