# Ruby: adding arrays of hashes (don't ask), delete if found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, hash

I asked a similar question recently that I solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38368397/rails-merge-array-of-hashes-based-on-keys-of-hashes), but I need to ask it again because my platform is unforgiving and the structure *must* be as follows:

```
"variables": [
  {
    "box": "info_top",
    "content": "Default info_top content"
  },
  {
    "box": "info_bottom",
    "content": "Default info_bottom content"
  },
  {
    "box": "info_top",
    "content": "NEW INFO TOP CONTENT"
  }
]
```

In short, I want to overwrite the first `info_top` hash in the above array with the second `info_top`. The method that builds this array looks like this:

```
def variables
  (template_variables + user_variables).sort_by do |k, _v|
    order.index k['box'].to_sym
  end
end
```

I need `user_variables` to replace any hash found in `template_variables` based on the hash's value of the `box` key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your arrays look like this:

```
template_variables = [
  {
    "box" => "info_top",
    "content" => "Default info_top content"
  },
  {
    "box" => "info_bottom",
    "content" => "Default info_bottom content"
  }
]

user_variables = [
  {
    "box" => "info_top",
    "content" => "NEW INFO TOP CONTENT"
  }
]
```

You can get there like this:

```
(user_variables + template_variables).uniq { |hash| hash["box"] }

 => [{"box"=>"info_top", "content"=>"NEW INFO TOP CONTENT"}, {"box"=>"info_bottom", "content"=>"Default info_bottom content"}]
```

Notice that user_varliables goes first when adding the arrays together.

EDIT:

So the final version should look like this:

```
def variables
  (user_variables + template_variables).uniq { |hash| hash["box"] }.sort_by do |k, _v|
    order.index k['box'].to_sym
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
variables.each_with_object([]) do |h, memo|
  if elem = memo.detect { |e| e['box'] == h['box'] }
    elem['content'] = h['content'] # we already have it ⇒ update
  else
    memo << h # new item ⇒ just insert
  end
end

#⇒ [
#    [0] {
#          "box" => "info_top",
#      "content" => "NEW INFO TOP CONTENT"
#    },
#    [1] {
#          "box" => "info_bottom",
#      "content" => "Default info_bottom content"
#    }
#  ]
```

Comment: What errors does it return? I did not get the question “what should `elem` be,” `elem` is a local variable here defined in the second line. BTW, on the input you provided both answers here work just pretty fine. It would be great if you’ll try to find the problem in problem description, fix it and then return back with claims “this is not working,“ because this works.

Comment: My bad, my linter changed your `=` to a double `==`.